# Facebook Sdk error

Tags: android, facebook

On posting Facebook i got `java.io.EOFException` sometimes.Is there any solution how to fix this.
This is my code for posting:

```
public void postPictureWithParams(final Context context, final FBInterface fbinterface,final Bitmap bitmap,final String msg) {
        Session.openActiveSession((Activity) context, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
              @Override
              public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

                if (session.isOpened() &&state.isOpened()&& hasPublishPermission(context)) {
                      Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
                    postParams.putString("message", msg);
                    byte[] data = null;
                     ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                     bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                     data = baos.toByteArray();
                     postParams.putByteArray("picture", data);
                        Request request = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(),"me/photos", postParams, HttpMethod.POST,  new Request.Callback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                                         if(response.getError()==null){
                                                fbinterface.success(null,response);
                                                 }else{
                                                     fbinterface.failure(response.getError());   
                                                 } 
                                    }
                                });
                        request.executeAsync();
                    }   
                }

            });

    }
```